# Knockout counter error (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have script written via Knockout JS.

Here is view code

```
 <span data-bind='text: numberOfClicks'>&nbsp;</span>/<span data-bind='text: totalnumberofClicks'>&nbsp;</span>
```

Here is code

```
 function count_blocks() {

    var length = $("#questions > div").length;
    var ClickCounterViewModel = function () {
        this.totalnumberofClicks = ko.observable(length);
        this.numberOfClicks = ko.observable(1);
        this.registerClick = function () {
            this.numberOfClicks(this.numberOfClicks() + 1);
            if (numberOfClicks >= totalnumberofClicks ) {
                alert("error!");

            }
        };
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ClickCounterViewModel());

}
```

I need to get alert when numberOfClicks >= totalnumberofClicks.

But I have error

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: numberOfClicks is not defined
    at ClickCounterViewModel.registerClick (2141:169)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (knockout-3.4.2.js:90)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: The `this` in `registerClick` doesn't always refer to your viewmodel instance. Either add `.bind(this)` to the function declaration or define it in our `prototype`. You can also bind it in your `click` binding using `data-bind="click: registerClick.bind($data)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` within `registerClick` is the scope within the method only. Access outer scope variables by binding it to `self` and use it as :

```
var ClickCounterViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.totalnumberofClicks = ko.observable(length);
    this.numberOfClicks = ko.observable(1);
    this.registerClick = function () {
        self.numberOfClicks(self.numberOfClicks() + 1);
        if (self.numberOfClicks() >= self.totalnumberofClicks()) {
            alert("error!");
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank's it helps a lot!